# VBA Excel: comparison of dates under different locale settings

Tags: excel, vba, date, type-conversion, date-conversion

I have a column in "dd-mm-yy hh:mm" format that formed as a result of some action on UserForm:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Logs")
With ws
  For i = 1 to Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    .Cells(lRow + 1 + i, 10).Value = CDate(VBA.Format(Me.ListBox1.List(i), "dd-mm-yy hh:mm"))
Next i
End With
```

[image: excel column with datetime]

I save the column to Variant variable to use later (to be used multiple times):

```
Dim arrTimeD As Variant
arrTimeD = Application.Transpose(.Range(TCL & "2:" & TCL & lRow).Value)
```

The locale date settings are European: "dd-mmm-yyyy"

The spreadsheet are used by different users, some have "dd-mmm" setting, others "mm-dd" etc.

I need to compare the dates in several uses. For, e.g.

```
Dim bDate as Date
bDate = CDate(VBA.Format(Me.lblCheckin.Caption,"dd-mm-yyyy"))
Do While CDate(arrTimeD(bIndex)) < bDate
      If bIndex = lRow - 1 Then Exit Do
      bIndex = bIndex + 1            
Loop
```

When the user with US locale ("mm-dd") uses the spreadsheet, `CDate(arrTimeD(bIndex))` throws error. `CDate(VBA.Format(arrTimeD(bIndex)))` and `CDate(DateValue(arrTimeD(bIndex))` didn't help. What is the best way to do it?
Is it possible to set workbook's own date setting regardless of OS's?
Or I need to convert variant to string then concatenate?

Answer (score 0):

The date string should be converted into a numeric date value.

```
Function DDMMYYYFormatToDateTimeValue(DateString As String) As Date
    Dim Parts() As String
    Parts = Split(DateString, "-")
    DDMMYYYFormatToDateTimeValue = CDate(Parts(1) & "/" & Parts(0) & "/" & Parts(2))
End Function
```

### Usage

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 1 To 100
        ListBox1.AddItem Format(Date + n / 24, "MM-DD-YY HH:MM")
    Next
End Sub

Public Function ListBoxDateValues()
    Dim Data As Variant
    ReDim Data(1 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim DateString As String
    
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount
        DateString = Me.ListBox1.List(r - 1)
        Data(r, 1) = DDMMYYYFormatToDateTimeValue(DateString)
    Next
    ListBoxDateValues = Data
End Function

Public Function wsLogs() As Worksheet
    Set wsLogs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Logs")
End Function

Function DDMMYYYFormatToDateTimeValue(DateString As String) As Date
    Dim Parts() As String
    Parts = Split(DateString, "-")
    DDMMYYYFormatToDateTimeValue = CDate(Parts(1) & "/" & Parts(0) & "/" & Parts(2))
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

First, true date values *carry no format*, so convert your text dates from the listbox directly to true date values:

```
.Cells(lRow + 1 + i, 10).Value = CDate(Me.ListBox1.List(i))
```

These you can apply the format you prefer for display.

The comparison is now straight:

```vb
Dim bDate As Date

bDate = CDate(Me.lblCheckin.Caption)
Do While arrTimeD(bIndex) < bDate
    If bIndex = lRow - 1 Then 
        Exit Do
    Else
        bIndex = bIndex + 1
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: So, if I do not format the cells when writing to cells CDate(VBA.Format(Me.ListBox1.List(i), "dd-mm-yy hh:mm")), the problem would be fixed? Please note that the date could be entered on a machine with European local settings, and later read on computer with US locale settings:

Do While CDate(arrTimeD(bIndex)) < bDate

Comment: Yes. If the dates are entered as _Date_, they will be numeric values, and these will be read correctly whatever the local date _format_ is, as the applied format is for display only.